# Mod-rewrite shortening imagelink

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a image gallery and I would like to have a bit shorter links.

So far I have:

http://site.com/up/fjr5Z <-this shows only the image

http://site.com/images.php <-this shows all the images in html page

This is my .htaccess file and all my images are at **http.//site.com/up/**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^img/([^/\.]+)/?$ images.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to get images work like this: **http.//site.com/fjr5Z**

Am I even close?

Comment: So you want from :  http://site.com/images.php?id=xx to  http.//site.us/fjr5Z ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks close, but you're matching against `img/` and not `up/`. It seems like that should be enough for `/up/fjr5Z` to get rewritten to `/images.php?id=fjr5Z`:

```
RewriteRule ^up/([^/\.]+)/?$ /images.php?id=$1 [L]
```

As far as getting urls to rewrite from `http.//site.com/fjr5Z`, you'll need to be sure that what you are matching against isn't going to interfere with something else. For example, if you have rules that rewrite things like `/post-title` to `/index.php?post=post-title`, there's going to have to be a way to differentiate between **post-title** and **fjr5Z**. If there isn't any other rules you have to worry about, you could simply try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/? /images.php?id=$1 [L]
```